# Trying to get PL/SQL WHILE LOOP to work with variables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a tough time trying to get this to work in Oracle SQL Developer.

I want to start a query, then after the first couple lines of it run a while loop to cycle through weeks. I haven't structered the entire query out yet because I can't even get as far as to figure out how to work with the WHILE LOOP like this.

Here is a simple example, I know I need to specify some date fields, etc but hopefully you get what I am going for. Basically trying to create a new column for each week of transactions. The default Oracle WW or IW values don't work for us.

I know there are a lot of other tweaks in this query that need to be straightened out, not too sure where commas should be and not. I'm not used to working in SQL Developer to do these tasks. Thank you for any feedback!

```
DECLARE
MyDayVar  VARCHAR2(20) := '05-JAN-14'; --sets the start of Week2
MyWeekVar VARCHAR2(20) := '2';
SELECT Customer_Name, 
sum(CASE when PLANNED_SHIP_DATE >= '01-JAN-14' and PLANNED_SHIP_DATE <= '04-JAN-14' then (REVISED_QTY_DUE - QTY_SHIPPED) * SALE_UNIT_PRICE end) as Wk1 --trying to get Week 1 of 2014,

WHILE 
MyDayVar =< '01-JAN-15'
LOOP

sum(CASE when PLANNED_SHIP_DATE >= :MyDayVar and PLANNED_SHIP_DATE <= (:MyDayVar + 7) then (REVISED_QTY_DUE - QTY_SHIPPED) * SALE_UNIT_PRICE end) as Wk + :MyWeekVar --trying to get Week 2 of 2014 and display as 'Wk2',
MyDayVar = :MyDayVar + 7; --add 7 days to MyDayVar to prepare for the next day;
MyWeekVar = :MyWeekVar + 1; --add 1 to the Week Variabkle;
FROM CUSTOM_ORDERS_TABLE
WHERE PLANNED_SHIP_DATE => '01-JAN-14' --only grab year 2014 data
END LOOP
```

Comment: You're using s string comparison to check `date` ?

Comment: "The default Oracle WW or IW values don't work for us."  Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by re-stating your question to make clear your actual aim: you want to aggregate the value of shipped orders for each week of the year.

Your definition of 'week' is seven days staring with the Sunday.  S,o unless 1st Jan is a Sunday, your first week will be short.  Presumably this requirement is why you cannot use the Oracle IW or WW format masks to generate the weekly buckets.  Fortunately Oracle has other useful date operations which can help to solve this problem.

We can use `trunc()` on dates with a format mask to get certain values.  So `trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')` gives us the first day of the current year.  We could hard-code 01-JAN-2014 but why not be more flexible?  Anyway, [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm#sthref1717).

We can use `next_day()` to give us the next date of the given day.  So `next_date(sysdate, 'SUN')` gives us the next Sunday.  Note that if today is a Sunday it will give us the date of *next* Sunday.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions106.htm#i78154).

We use arithmetical operations on dates.  So `sysdate+7` gives us the date of this day next week.

One other useful construct is subquery factoring, AKA the `with` clause.  Intended to improve the efficiency of subqueries which appear more than once in a query it also provides a way to generate sets of data.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2077142).  In the PoC code below I use Oracle's [hierarchical query construct](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2066102) to generate a set of all the Sundays in the year.

So with all these tools at our finger tips it becomes possible to solve your problem in a single query without using PL/SQL at all:

```
with yr as ( select next_day(trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')-1, 'SUN') as first_sunday
              from dual )
     , sundays as ( select first_sunday + ((level-1)*7) as this_sunday
                         , first_sunday + ((level-2)*7) as prev_sunday
                 from yr
                 connect by level <= 53 ) 
select sundays.this_sunday as sunday
       , sum ( case when t.planned_ship_date >= sundays.prev_sunday
                       and t.planned_ship_date < sundays.this_sunday
                  then ((t.revised_qty_due - t.qty_shipped) * t.sale_unit_price)
                  else 0 end ) as wk_total
from sundays
     cross join custom_orders_table t
where t.planned_ship_date between date '2014-01-01' and date '2014-12-31'
group by sundays.this_sunday
order by sundays.this_sunday
```

The SQL Fiddle has a simplified version of your problem.  [Check it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4c3f/4).